# clean divide Code and Gui

Tags: python, user-interface, model-view-controller, interface

Hi I know this is a pretty basic design question. But I don't realy get it....
I write it in Python with PySide, but I think this is more a language unrelated question.
A simplified example what I want to do:

I Have a Gui with a button that opens a file dialog. 
In this one I choose a folder.
The code scans the suffixes of the files in the folder and returns the 3 needed one. lets say .mp3, .txt and .mov and shows them in the gui.

To this point the seperation should be no problem I would have a Gui class that runs the code of the core class, gets the three files as return values and sets up the gui.

What I am wondering about is what happens when there are more then one files matching the .mp3 suffix. I would want to have a pop up with a combobox to select the one I want to use. But I don't realy get how to implement it without adding gui code to the core class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well maybe have the function in the Core module return some specifier that such a thing has happened (found multiple) along with the given names, then display the choice to the user and call a function in the Core module that returns relevant information about that file.

Bear in mind you do not have to be *dogmatic* regarding such restrictions, there are some situations where having code in the GUI is much less of a hassle than having to integrate some way of it to work in between modules.

This is where you make a decision how to go about writing the code, bearing in mind how important this feature is to you, how testable/maintainable you need it to be.